# C fork() children killed or in eternal loop?

Tags: c, tcp, fork

I am making an assignment in which a server fork's multiple children, one for each sensor connected to the server (and each child then has a tcp connection to that sensor node).

Now as it's my first time working with fork's, I'm not entirely sure it's working correctly.

The `tcpsocket.h` is a file provided, giving some basic tcp-functionality. This is working, since the data is sent and received succesfully.

Here's a short explanation of the code: The main process listens passively to incoming tcp connections. The `tcp_wait_for_connection()` waits in blocking mode for a connection to be established. Once this is done, it should give the connection to a new child. The Child should of course then close the passive listening on the port, and the main process should not listen to the connection with the sensor.

Now it all works fine, but I'm not sure whether children are correctly killed. A sensorNode for example just quits (cntrl + c), thus the connection stops, but I'm not sure whether the child then dies or keeps looping for eternity. I've also included `tcpsocket.c` since this might give more clarity.

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "tcpsocket.h"

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define PORT 1234

struct package{
    unsigned sensorId:12;
    unsigned sequence:4;
    unsigned flag:2;
    unsigned sign:1;
    unsigned value:12;
    unsigned parity:1;
};

typedef struct package packs;

union sensor{
    packs pack;
    unsigned sensorValue;
};

typedef union sensor Sensor;

char buffer[BUFSIZE];

int main( void )
{
    Socket server, client;
    int bytes;

    server = tcp_passive_open( PORT );

    while( 1 ) {
        client = tcp_wait_for_connection( server );

        #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Incoming client connection\n");
        #endif

        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1){
            printf("Something went wrong creating a child.\n");
        }else if(pid == 0){
            tcp_close( &server );

            #ifdef DEBUG
                pid_t parentPid;
                parentPid = getppid();
                printf("New child created with parent id %d, own pid: %d\n",parentPid, pid);
            #endif

            Sensor * mySensor = malloc(sizeof(packs));

            while(1){
                memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);

                bytes = tcp_receive( client, (void *)buffer, BUFSIZE );

                if(bytes > 0){
                    mySensor->sensorValue = atoi(buffer);
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                        printf("Received message of %d bytes. ID: %i, Sequence: %i, flag: %i, sign: %i, value: %i\n", 
                            bytes, mySensor->pack.sensorId, mySensor->pack.sequence, mySensor->pack.flag, mySensor->pack.sign, mySensor->pack.value);
                    #endif
                }
            }
            tcp_close( &client );
            exit(0);
        }
        tcp_close( &client );
    }
    tcp_close( &server );
    return 0;
}
```

**tcpsocket.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "tcpsocket.h"

#define CHAR_IP_ADDR_LENGTH 16     // 4 numbers of 3 digits, 3 dots and \0
#define ERROR_SD -1
#define ERROR_PORT 0
#define MIN_PORT 1
#define MAX_PORT 65536

#define PROTOCOLFAMILY  AF_INET     // internet protocol suite
#define TYPE        SOCK_STREAM // streaming protool type
#define PROTOCOL    IPPROTO_TCP     // TCP protocol 

typedef struct {
  int sd;
  char *ip_addr;
  int port;   
  } MySocket;       // My definition of a socket: a socket descriptor, 
            // the IP address and port number of the PC hosting this socket 

// private functions used for error checking
static void die(char* message);
static void check_socket_ptr(char *pre_msg, Socket s);
static void check_sd(char *pre_msg, int sd);
static void check_ip_addr(char *pre_msg, char *ip_addr);
static void check_port(char *pre_msg, int port);

// private error message string
static char error_msg[256]; 

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Socket tcp_passive_open(int port) 
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check                                                                                         
  check_port("tcp_open_server() failed", port);

  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)malloc( sizeof(MySocket) );
  if ( s == NULL ) 
    die("tcp_open__socket() failed: mem alloc error");

  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  s->sd = socket(PROTOCOLFAMILY, TYPE, PROTOCOL);
  check_sd("tcp_open_server failed(): socket creation error", s->sd);

  /* Construct the server address structure */
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  addr.sin_family = PROTOCOLFAMILY;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if ( bind(s->sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 ) {
    die("tcp_open_server failed(): bind() failed");  //will fail if e.g; port is in use
  }

  if( listen(s->sd, MAX_PENDING) != 0 )
    die("tcp_open_server failed(): listen() failed");

  s->port = port;
  s->ip_addr = NULL;  //INADDR_ANY ...  

  return (Socket)s;  
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Socket tcp_active_open( int remote_port, char *remote_ip ) 
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check                                                                                         
  check_port("tcp_open_client() failed", remote_port);
  check_ip_addr("tcp_open_client() failed", remote_ip);

  MySocket *client = (MySocket *)malloc( sizeof(MySocket) );
  if ( client == NULL ) 
    die("tcp_open_client() failed: mem alloc error");

  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  int length;
  char *p;

  client->sd = socket(PROTOCOLFAMILY, TYPE, PROTOCOL);
  check_sd("tcp_open_client() failed: socket creation error", client->sd);

  /* Construct the server address structure */
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  addr.sin_family = PROTOCOLFAMILY;
  if ( inet_aton(remote_ip, (struct in_addr *) &addr.sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) 
    die("tcp_open_client failed(): invalid ip address");

  addr.sin_port = htons(remote_port);

  if ( connect(client->sd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr) ) < 0 )
    die("tcp_open_client failed(): connect () failed");

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  length = sizeof(addr);
  if ( getsockname(client->sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&length) != 0 )
    die("tcp_open_client failed(): getsockname() failed");

  p = inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr);  //returns addr to statically allocated buffer

  client->ip_addr = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char)*CHAR_IP_ADDR_LENGTH);
  if ( client->ip_addr == NULL )
    die("tcp_open_client failed(): mem alloc error");
  client->ip_addr = strcpy( client->ip_addr, p );
  client->port = ntohs(addr.sin_port);

  return (Socket)client;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Socket tcp_wait_for_connection( Socket socket ) 
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check                                                                                         
  check_socket_ptr("tcp_wait_for_connection() failed", socket);

  MySocket *serv = (MySocket *)socket;
  MySocket *clie = (MySocket *)malloc( sizeof(MySocket) );
  if ( clie == NULL ) 
    die("tcp_wait_for_connection() failed: mem alloc error");

  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  char *p;

  check_sd("tcp_wait_for_connection() failed", serv->sd);

  clie->sd = accept(serv->sd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &length);

  check_sd("tcp_wait_for_connection() failed: accept() error", clie->sd);

  p = inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr);  //returns addr to statically allocated buffer
  clie->ip_addr = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char)*CHAR_IP_ADDR_LENGTH);
  if ( clie->ip_addr == NULL )
    die("tcp_wait_for_connection failed(): mem alloc error");
  clie->ip_addr = strcpy( clie->ip_addr, p );
  clie->port = ntohs(addr.sin_port);

  return (Socket)clie;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void tcp_close( Socket *socket )
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check                
  check_socket_ptr("tcp_close() failed", socket);                                                                         
  check_socket_ptr("tcp_close() failed", *socket);

  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)*socket;

  check_sd("tcp_close() failed", s->sd);

  close( s->sd );

  free(s);

  *socket = NULL;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void tcp_send(Socket socket, void *buffer, int bufsize ) 
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check                                                                                         
  check_socket_ptr("tcp_send() failed", socket);

  if ( buffer == NULL ) 
    die("tcp_send failed(): buffer param is NULL");

  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)socket;
  int result;
  int sen = 0;
  int to_sen = bufsize;

  check_sd("tcp_send() failed", s->sd);

  do {
    result = send(s->sd, (const void*) (buffer+sen), to_sen, 0);
    if (result < 0)
      die("tcp_send() failed: not able to send");
    sen += result;
    to_sen -= result;
  } while ( to_sen > 0 );

}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int tcp_receive (Socket socket, void* buffer, int bufsize) 
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check                                                                             
  check_socket_ptr("tcp_receive() failed", socket);

  if ( buffer == NULL ) 
    die("tcp_receive() failed: buffer param is NULL");
  if ( bufsize == 0 ) 
    die("tcp_receive() failed: bufsize is zero");

  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)socket;

  check_sd("tcp_receive() failed", s->sd);

  int rec = recv(s->sd, buffer, bufsize, 0);

  return rec;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char * get_ip_addr( Socket socket ) 

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{   
  // parameter check
  check_socket_ptr("get_ip_addr() failed", socket);

  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)socket;

  check_ip_addr("get_ip_addr() failed", s->ip_addr);

  return s->ip_addr;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int get_port( Socket socket ) 

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check
  check_socket_ptr("get_port() failed", socket);

  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)socket;

  check_port("get_port() failed", s->port);

  return s->port;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int get_socket_descriptor( Socket socket )
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  // parameter check
  check_socket_ptr("get_socket_descriptor() failed", socket);

  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)socket;

  check_sd("get_socket_descriptor() failed", s->sd);

  return s->sd;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void die(char* message)
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  perror(message);
  exit(-1);
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void check_socket_ptr(char *pre_msg, Socket socket) 
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  if ( socket == NULL ) 
  {
    sprintf(error_msg, "%s: socket ptr is NULL", pre_msg);
    die(error_msg);   
  }                                                                                      
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/       
static void check_sd(char *pre_msg, int sd)
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{ 
  if ( sd <= ERROR_SD ) 
  {
    sprintf(error_msg, "%s: invalid socket descriptor", pre_msg);
    die(error_msg); 
  } 
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void check_ip_addr(char *pre_msg, char *ip_addr)
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  if ( ip_addr == NULL )
  { 
    sprintf(error_msg, "%s: invalid socket ip address", pre_msg);
    die(error_msg);
  } 
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void check_port(char *pre_msg, int port)
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
  if ( (port < MIN_PORT) || (port > MAX_PORT) )
  {
    sprintf(error_msg, "%s: invalid socket port", pre_msg);
    die(error_msg);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Too much code... Please trim to problem code

Comment: alk already give the correct answer. But one more notice: Current code seems to generate zombie processes. Use waitpid() function or 'double fork()' trick for avoiding zombies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether the child then dies or keeps looping for eternity.

In the code you show there are no tests for `recv()` returning `0` which would indicate that the connection had been closed by the other side.

You might like to modify the code like this

```
            if(bytes > 0){
                mySensor->sensorValue = atoi(buffer);
                #ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("Received message of %d bytes. ID: %i, Sequence: %i, flag: %i, sign: %i, value: %i\n", 
                        bytes, mySensor->pack.sensorId, mySensor->pack.sequence, mySensor->pack.flag, mySensor->pack.sign, mySensor->pack.value);
                #endif
            }
            else if (bytes == 0)
            {
              printf("Connection closed by other side. Exiting ...\n");
              break;
            }
            else /* bytes < 0 */
            {
              printf("Error receiving. Exiting ...\n");
              break;
            }
```

to end the child. There is no need to "kill" any process in term of sending it a `SIGKILL` signal, btw.

---

Also the `tcp_receive()` function misses to test how much data had been received for each call to `recv()` and then if necessary to loop around `recv()` until all data requested had been received. (See `tcp_send()` to see how it is done for `send()`.)

Comment: Wasn't aware that `bytes == 0` meant the connection had been closed, very handy. As for the `tcp_receive()`, it is given to us for the assignment and thus is not allowed to be modified. The packages that are sent are kept very small however, so for this proof of concept it should not give any issues.